# Unregistering a (specific) serviceworker fails in IE, while code is OK in Chrome

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I want to unregister a service-worker from my site using the following JS code:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then(function(registrations) {
    for(let registration of registrations) {
        if (registration.active.scriptURL === 'https://myapp.mydomain.com/siteworker-sw.js') {
            registration.unregister();
        }
    }
});
```

While this runs OK in Chrome, IE 11 raises an error

```
';' expected
```

May someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: try `var registration in registrations`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for..of` statement is bombing out since [it's not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility).